# Adding if statement in a try/except bloc

Tags: python, debugging, try-except

I' learning Python and I wonder if improving my code with a light *debug level* with if statement in my try/except bloc may be a good practice or if there is a better (or builtin) way to doing this.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
""" Testing conditions in try/except """

DEBUG_MODE = True
number = input("Type a integer: ")

try:
    number = int(number)
except ValueError as except_detail:
    if DEBUG_MODE:
        print("ValueError: «{}»".format(except_detail))
    else:
        print("«{}» is not an integer".format(number))            
else:
    print("Your number {} is an integer".format(number))
```

I use a boolean, but a debug-level `list()` work either for more than 2 levels.

Error reporting may also be improved with *debug-level specific* logging instructions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use Python's `logging` module for this, you can change the logging `level` argument to record the level of logging detail you want:

```
import logging

logging.basicConfig(filename='log.txt', filemode='a', level=logging.DEBUG)

try:
    number = int(number)
except ValueError as except_detail:
    logging.warning("ValueError: «{}»".format(except_detail))
    logging.info("«{}» is not an integer".format(number))         
else:
    logging.info("Your number {} is an integer".format(number))
```

Comment: Interesting, I do not need (yet) loging feature. I imagine that it do not manipulate message without writing in a file?

Comment: OK, I just look at the [basic tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging.html#logging-basic-tutorial), loggin on screen or in file can be set easily. Sounds great! Thx.

Comment: @freezed Happy to help!

Answer (score 0):

The standard library has the logging module is designed for this: https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html  has built in log levels debug, info, warning, error, critical

Comment: … and in [python3](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html) too.